# Вирусы на компьютере и их опасность

Tags: безопасность, вирусы, антивирус

Проверила комп антивирем нпшет такие вирусы:

1.Trojan.Genetic.Win32

2.Trojan.Genetic

3.Win32/trojan.e6d

5.Win64/Trojan.4b0

Genetic/Trojan.PWS.804

6.Что то вроде adware

7.Malware.gen И ещё там множество Genetic 
Могут ли эти вирусы дать хакнру доступ к моей веб камере и следить за мной, если я посмотрела и в разделе веб-угрозы в моем антивирусе пусто? Меня это слишком волнует, ведь моя жизнь может быть скомпроментирована

Comment: скачайте утилитку от касперского - почистите

Comment: https://www.kaspersky.ru/downloads/thank-you/free-virus-removal-tool

Comment: год назад ? простите вот этого я не знаю - что у вас было год назад

Comment: @MaximLensky мне сейчас уже не важно следят или не мне важно год назад а именно были вот эти вирусы, я не знаю как жить с этим страхом и мне нужно знать могли ли следить

Comment: @MaximLensky там были эти же вирусы у меня в то время не было антивируса и я ничего не удалалось. А сейчас я начала переживать о слежке в то время но хотя бы у меня есть список вирусов, и я не знаю 3ак узнать следили или нет.

Comment: @MaximLensky а зачем специально для меня писать программу? Вирусов в интернете море скачивай не хочу. И я угодила вот в лапы этих вирусов  и теперь мне страшно

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что явно не по теме.

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас есть Windows10, активируйте собственную программу Windows Defender. Настройте постоянное обновление. Все проверено на себе и защищает вас

Comment: Мне уже не важно следят ли сейчас, мнеажно могли ли следить

Comment: Вы знаете Эдварда Сноудена? Если вы не знаете, есть кино посмотреть, это было в нашей жизни, если у вас ест интернет. В любом случае, они следуют.

Вот этот фильм, если вы еще не видели. Фильм снят из реальной жизни: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q05LvOUXXUo

Comment: Да но спец службы мне пофиг, я боюсь что моя личная жизнь попадёт в сеть

Comment: Речь идет о том, что там все наблюдают. По этой причине трудно ответить на этот вопрос. Лучше установить Windows снова и активировать Защитник Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Если у взломщика есть (скорее всего так и есть) доступ управляющего (главной учётки), то да, могут получить и сведения и с камеры.

Защита:

1. Заклеить лентой. Отклеивать будете, в случае необходимости. Так не "подсмотрят", чем занимаетесь. Если же боитесь, что вообще узнают, о чём вели беседу, то лучше их не ведите в таком виде вовсе, ибо промежуточных узлов уйма, с которых выложенное в сеть может "утечь" в сторону: вы, ваш собеседник и т.д.
2. Остаётся встроенный звукопис (микрофон). Тоже заклеить можно, чем плотнее, тем лучше. Проверить надёжность можно запустив речепис (диктофон) на вычислителе (компьютере) и попробовав произнести несколько слов.

Можно ли узнать о том, что записи передавались?

1. Для простого человека почти невозможно, если передаваемые по сети данные не записывались в соответствующие дневники действий (логи). Так что, если они были переданы, то узнать об этом вы сможете только косвенно. Например, по изменению поведения окружающих.

Помогут ли обновления в этом деле?

1. Если коротко, то лишь частично. Так как даже если ваш противовред (антивирус) молчит, то это не значит, что за вами не следят. Эти приложения призваны отыскивать определённого рода угрозы, но не все, а способов было придумано уйма за эти десятилетия.

Как избавиться от страха преследования?

1. Вспомним советы одного известного еврейского царя по имени Соломон: "*Нечестивый бежит, когда никто не гонится за ним; а праведник смел, как лев.*". Т.е. не делайте и не посещайте ничего дурного, когда пользуетесь вычислителем и будет вам спокойствие. Исходите из того, что всё то, что смотрите, читаете и видите вы, смогут увидеть, услышать и узнать другие. Вспомним образ Джима Кэрри в его "Шоу Трумена" (Показ Настоящегочеловека).
2. Самообразовываться в направлении по защите своих сведений. Впрочем это не быстро.

ПС (ПослеСловие. Post Scriptum). Хакер (hacker) — это не преступник, а человек, отлично знающий своё дело. В целом это сродни слову "знаток", причём в любом деле. Те же, кого имеешь в виду, это взломщики. К примеру, вот врач, знаток (хакер) в деле врачевания. Он может лечить. Также он может и травить (вредить). Однако его называют врач, потому что он лечит. Вот если бы он начал травить, вот тогда мы бы звали его отравителем, а не врачом.